# In React, the searhbox won't work properly

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner to learn about React. I tried to follow up on one Udemy lecture but my searchbox didn't work as well even though I rewrite the code three times... Could you check this code why my searchbox didn't work? If I type some words in searchbox, it should show matched cards(write down name on search box and it shows a matched card)

I will share my code bellow

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'tachyons';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

reportWebVitals();
```

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import {robots} from './robots';
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            robots: robots,
            searchfield: ''
        }
    }
// With anything that comes from React, so constructor and render are pre-built in React
// any time you make your own methods on a componet, we have to use arror function
    onSearchCange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value })
        // console.log(event.target.value);
        // console.log(filteredRobots);
    }

    render() {
        const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
            return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
        })
    return (
        <div className='tc'>
            <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
            <SearchBox searchCange={this.onSearchCange} />
            <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
        </div>
        );  
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is SearchBox.jss

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox = ({ searchfield, searchChange}) => {
    return (
        <div className='pa2'>
            <input
                className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
                type='search'
                placeholder='search robots'
                onChange={searchChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
} 

export default SearchBox;
```

This is CardList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const CardList = ({ robots }) => {
    const cardComponent = robots.map((user, i) => {
        return (<Card
         key={i}
         id={robots[i].id}
         name={robots[i].name}
         email={robots[i].email}
         />
        );
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {cardComponent}
        </div>      
    );
}
```

This is Card.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
    const {name, email, id} = props;
    return (
        <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shawdow-5'>
            <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200*200`} />
            <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}

export default Card;
```

This is robots.js

```
export const robots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
    username: 'Kamren',
    email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Mrs. Dennis Schulist',
    username: 'Leopoldo_Corkery',
    email: 'Karley_Dach@jasper.info'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Kurtis Weissnat',
    username: 'Elwyn.Skiles',
    email: 'Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V',
    username: 'Maxime_Nienow',
    email: 'Sherwood@rosamond.me'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Glenna Reichert',
    username: 'Delphine',
    email: 'Chaim_McDermott@dana.io'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Clementina DuBuque',
    username: 'Moriah.Stanton',
    email: 'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz'
  }
];
```

Thank you for helping me out in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a misspelling on line 31 in App.js

`<SearchBox searchCange={this.onSearchCange} />`

Your event is 'searchChange' not 'searchCange' and the line after fixing should look like this:

`<SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchCange} />`